# WebApi project, can't reach localhost via Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, firefox, visual-studio-code, postman

I have a basic WebApi project (Microsoft Weather Forcast example)

When I open and run the project in VS Code, webpage opens in existing Firefox window and I can perform queries via Postman.

When I open and run the project in Visual Studio 2019, separate Firefox window opens and I can't reach localhost, because of the following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
```

How can I reach my API running the project via Visual Studio 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following helped me:

Project => Properties => Debug:

Set App URL: https://localhost:44351/ (or whatever port you want)

Enable SSL: True

web.config:

```
<environmentVariables>
  <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44351" />
</environmentVariables>
```